# Migration dialog on non-mobile site is not rendered well in iOS Safari

Tags: feature-request, mobile-safari, migration

On my iPhone, in Safari, the SO migration dialogue looks like this:

[image]

Seems counter-intuitive to render the shorter options in a smaller font, and might be misinterpretted as somehow guiding the closer away from these options.

Could this be revised so that the font for superuser and sharepoint are the same size as for the other sites, despite their one-line descriptions?

*Update:
I'm accessing this from the CV Review Queue, of which there is no mobile version, hence perhaps the request should be: Please can we present the mobile-optimised dialog when processing the review queue on a mobile device?*

Comment: So use the mobile version. The full version is not at all optimized for mobile devices. I'm not sure it's even SO doing that. Inspecting those elements reveals they have the exact same classes and styles.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said that this is in the context of processing the Close Vote Queue.  Is doing that from mobile frowned upon (I don't see how to navigate to a mobile version of that.)

Comment: There is no mobile version of review (yet), but that doesn't mean they should be optimizing full-site features for the sake of review from mobile devices. And as stated, it might just be your browser. There's nothing in the HTML or CSS that would cause that as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes, I see.  Seems possibly related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303263.

Answer (score 1):

On my iPhone, in Safari, the SO migration dialogue looks like this:

[image: Migration Dialogue]

Maybe you should consider using the mobile site on your iPhone?